# Saving data to json using nodejs and cointicker

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, angular, bitcoin

Im learning nodejs and I'm creating a server to get the price of cryptocurrencies using a npm called Coin-Ticker. I want to use the data I'm getting in an Angular app but it's not displaying the data in the html. This is my code:

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const coinTicker = require('coin-ticker');

const api = require('./server/routes/api');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));

app.use('/api', api);

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
});


const port = process.env.PORT || '3000';
app.set('port', port);

const server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port, () => console.log(`API running on localhost:${port}`));
```

API.JS

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const coinTicker = require('coin-ticker');

/* GET api listing. */
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('api works');
});

router.get((req, res) => {
  coinTicker('bitfinex', 'BTC_USD')
    .then(posts => {
      res.status(200).json(posts.data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      res.status(500).send(error)
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What errors are you getting in the console? Any logs from the terminal? What's in your index.html? Also `router.get((req, res) => {` seems wrong... you need a path as the first argument I think.

Comment: thanks for your reply @lxe. No log at all from the terminal and the html is just receiving the data.
I tried to follow this example: https://scotch.io/tutorials/mean-app-with-angular-2-and-the-angular-cli

Comment: The client and the server are independent applications. Determine if your server application returns the expected data. If it does then your issue is in the client application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because coin ticker returns the json in the then so when you are doing `res.status(200).json(posts.data);` it is returning undefined. just replace that with `res.status(200).json(posts)` and it should work

Also you can not do `router.get((req, res) => {`
you need a path before this. I tried this code with 
`router.get('/convert', (req, res) => {` and with the changes above it worked

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it doesnt work. The html and the console are not displaying any info. This the tutorial I tried to follow :scotch.io/tutorials/mean-app-with-angular-2-and-the-angular-cli

If I follow that example step by step it works, but not when I try to use cointicker.

Comment: ok just to be clear if you add '/change' to the prefix then when you call it, it will need to be called with the url "/api/convert". To check if your server is working in the terminal just write `curl "localhost:3000/api/convert"` (make it use the proper port instead of 3000) and see if you get the correct response or you could go the page "localhost:3000/api/convert"